# kerberos : kinit not picking up updated values in krb5.conf

Tags: kerberos

We are running `kinit` from our Linux command line  and this works well. Before we run `kinit` we set the KRB5_CONFIG environment variable to point to directory continaing `krb5.conf` file

```
linuxhost1$ export KRB5_CONFIG=/myhome/mydir1/
linuxhost1$ kinit myuser@myrealm -k -t /myhome/mydir1/myname.keytab
```

Once the `kinit` works successfully what we noticed is if we change the values in `krb5.conf` in `/myhome/mydir1/` to point to invalid hostname etc., the `kinit` still works regardless of we running `kdestroy`, logging out and logging back.

Can someone please let us know if this is expected and how we would have the `kinit` command pick up the updated values in `krb5.conf` file?